# C program - works in linux; runtime failure in windows

Tags: c, linux, windows

I have done a *phonebook* program in **C** (with dinamical structs and so on).

It works perfectly under linux but when I try to run it (after compilation in **devc++**) in Windows it starts OK but after I add some data to the list it just stops and quits. Thats happening *only by adding a new data* to the phone book. When I'm working with other functions it's OK no interrupts and so on.

At the beginning of the module I attached `windows.h` and `conio.h` for `getch()` and `systen("cls")`. Maybe I used some functions that is not allowed in Windows or smth like that.

That is my first c-project, and usually I'm working in linux, so what should I pay attantion to?

```
/*SCREEN*/
#ifdef __WIN32__                                           /*for Windows*/
#include<windows.h>
#define GETCH printf("press ENTER...\n");getch() 
#define CLEAR system("cls")
#endif
#ifdef __unix__                                             /*for unix*/
#include<unistd.h> 
#define GETCH printf("\n\npress ENTER...");getchar()
#define CLEAR system("clear")
#endif
```

I also add name and pnonenumber the same way

```
printf("++ ADD DATA: ++\n");
         /*LASTNAME*/
                 printf(">> add lastname :  ");
                 fgets(buf,128,stdin);
                 lastname = malloc(strlen(buf));     /*allocate memory for lastdane*/ 
                 if( lastname != NULL)               /*successful allocation*/
                 {
                   strcpy( lastname, buf );          /*copy data from buf to lastname variable*/
                   lastname[strlen(lastname)-1]='\0';/*get the number of elements and add '\0' at the end*/
                 }
                 else                                /*allocation failed*/
                 {
                   printf("Memory Allocation Error!");
                 }
                 memset(buf,0,128);
```

---

```
void AddDATAsorted( char* lastname, char* firstname, char* telnumber )
{
  tDATA* pDATA;

  if( pTELBOOK )
  {
      pDATA = malloc( sizeof( tDATA ));         /*allocate memory for new item*/

      pDATA->lastname   = lastname;    
      pDATA->firstname  = firstname;
      pDATA->telnumber  = telnumber;

      addItemToList( pTELBOOK, pDATA, fcmp );   /*add a new item sorted - see list.c*/
  }
} /*END 6*/
```

its in another module.

---

```
int fcmp( void* pItemList, void* pItemNew )
{
  tDATA* pDATA_list;
  tDATA* pDATA_new;
  int diff;

  if( pItemList != NULL ) 
  {
      pDATA_list = ( tDATA* ) pItemList;          /*because void-pointer  */
      pDATA_new  = ( tDATA* ) pItemNew;

      diff = strcmp( pDATA_list->lastname, pDATA_new->lastname );
      if( diff != 0 ) return diff;
      else                                        /*if items have the same lastname*/                                    
      {
          diff = strcmp( pDATA_list->firstname, pDATA_new->firstname );
          if( diff != 0 ) return diff;
          else                                    /*if items have also the same firstname*/
          {
              diff = strcmp( pDATA_list->telnumber, pDATA_new->telnumber );
              if( diff != 0 ) return diff;
              else  return FAIL;                  /*if items - equal*/
          }
      }
  }
  else return OK;
```

debugger shows always that smth wrong here...

/* 2 * Function: REMOVE DATA*/

```
int RemoveDATA( void )
{
  tDATA* pDATA = NULL;
  if( pTELBOOK == NULL ) return FAIL;       
  else                                      /*if pTELBOOK's current element - not empty - free allocated memory*/
  {
     if( pTELBOOK->pCurr != NULL )
     { 
           pDATA = pTELBOOK->pCurr->pItem;
           free( pDATA->lastname );
           free( pDATA->firstname );
           free( pDATA->telnumber );
           free( pTELBOOK->pCurr->pItem );
           RemoveItem( pTELBOOK );            /*and remove element from the list*/
           return OK;                        
     }
  }
} /*END 2*/
```

Comment: You'll get much more useful feedback if you post your code.  Or a small example if your code is too long to usefully post.

Comment: Run the program under the debugger so you can follow what it's doing?

Comment: Your program is likely crashing. Use a debugger to find out where and come back with a more specific question that can provide relevant code.

Comment: I don't think you need `windows.h`

Comment: We need to see RemoveItem, addItemToList, and the definition of the tDATA structure and any substructures within.  One question: do you really mean RemoveItem(pTELBOOK) in RemoveDATA?  It's not clear what that's supposed to do.

Comment: Run the problem code step by step, and finally locate what's wrong. I think you problem is NOT that hard to locate. Just run the code step by step.

Answer (score 5):

```
             lastname = malloc(strlen(buf)); /* problem */ 
             if( lastname != NULL)
             {
               strcpy( lastname, buf);
               lastname[strlen(lastname)-1]='\0';
             }
```

use **strdup**. lastname's length is one shorter than needed. This could be a problem:

```
       lastname = strdup(buf);
```

Moreover, you should not use 128 or whatever. Use `sizeof buf` or `sizeof (buf)` instead, or maybe a define:

```
             #define BUF_SIZE   128
```

I've not checked the rest.

Comment: With some optimization flags, `-O2`, it would probably fail on linux as well then...

Comment: of course. I think (but I may be wrong) it seems safe because malloc rounds the requested length so that the heap allocated for real is often longer than the string length+1 -- the way malloc actualy reserves memory for the process can make the difference. But it's a hypothesis: maybe your program on windows crash elsewhere! Check it with a debugger (though, this does not mean this is not a real bug in your code: it means there could be other bugs...)

Comment: thanx everybody...maybe u re right...and the mistake is welsewhere

Comment: (just to be sure: the one I've pointed out is a mistake. But in windows as in linux it could be "silent". If it is so, it means there's another mistake that makes windows unhappy. Simply, fix this one and retry: if it crashes again, you have another bug)